# How to consolidate multiple cucumber reports to get 1 summarised report?

Tags: java, json, ruby, cucumber, reporting

I am executing 2 jobs on `Jenkins` which gives me 2 `cucumber.json` files as reports for each job. The first job is `Ruby` based and the second job is `Java` based. I get a cucumber report in Jenkins at the end of each job but what I need now is a consolidation of both reports into a single report. How do I do this? Your feedback is very much appreciated.

I've tried looking for a solution to combine the `cucumber.json` files from both job runs but could not find any.

Comment: Afaik this is not supported.

Comment: Checke [report builder](https://github.com/rajatthareja/ReportBuilder)